# How do you use plugins in Vim?

Tags: vim, plugins

I feel dense asking this but I've been playing with [the "textfilter" plugin](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/textfilter.html) for Vim, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

I have a text file open just now, and I want to find the longest line by using the plugin but I can't seem to run it.

I've tried: `:textfilter`, `|textfilter-find-longest-line|`, and a few others but it won't seem to run although I'm sure it's installed correctly as it's just a case of extracting to the correct location. It also reacts fine to `help textfilter`, but getting the help page is as close as I get to running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use a plugin should be documented along with the code that implements the plugin, there is no standard way to use plugins in general.

The help for that specific plugin indicates that it is for use from the GUI only, and it appears that it creates menu items for the various functions that it implements. There may be undocumented ways to use the functions without the menu items, or it could be that the plugin just doesn't load at all if you're not using the GUI.

Comment: Yeah, turns out it worked with GVim! Thank you! :)